# Generate Hg diff (or patch) that Only includes content for files modified by a revision/revset

Tags: version-control, mercurial, diff

Given a large codebase and two revisions or revsets (say, a local 'source' and a target) which may or may not share a recent parent and usually contain a large number of non-relevant file deltas;

How can diff output be generated to compare the changes *only for* files that are modified in the source revset itself?

(This should be the delta between the ancestry; but *only* for the files contained within the revset.)

Using `hg diff -r target -r source` shows *all* the changes in the ancestry, even for files not modified by the source sevision.

In addition, this should be done without any knowledge of the directory structure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you want a diff between revs `source` and `target`, but you want to restrict it to the files that were modified in changeset `source`. You can do it in two steps (easily assembled into one with an alias or shell script):

1. List the files modified in `source`:

   ```sh
   hg log -r source --template '{files}'
   ```

   This just outputs a list of filenames.
2. Request a diff for these files:

   ```sh
   hg diff -r target -r source $(hg log -r source --template '{files}')
   ```

Step 2 is a bash command with "command substitution" `$(...)`, which inserts the output of step one. Other methods are possible.

Comment: This is what I am looking for. I was hoping for a 'built-in' function, but this is definitely cleaner than the `xargs` approach I was using. Now to just adapt it to PowerShell for my co-workers :}

Answer (score 0):

From `hg help diff`

> If only one revision is specified then that revision is compared to the working directory

i.e. you can try `hg up $SOURCE; hg diff -r $TARGET`

Comment: Assuming a clean working directory this seems to be equivalent to `hg diff -r $TARGET -r .`, which also captures the diffs from *all* the files that differ in the ancestry (ie. not just those modified under a specific revset).

Comment: I also tried it with a dirty working directory (and a single -r) and it shows a diff of *all* modified files in the ancestry.